# Statistics on where Malicious Hackers / Spammers live

Tags: statistics, global, spam-prevention, blacklist, botnet

Does anyone have any ideas on where the worst Global Hackers Live (from a USA perspective). By this I mean, where do warez, serialz, botnets, spammers have their residence? In what countries are those hackers most likely to live? How do they connect to the internet? Is banning their home continent effective in curbing their access? (or do they use unknown proxies?)

I want to block likely hackers based on IP address / contient (i.e. China / Russia). I don't care if I alienate a large group of users.

Also, any freely available blocklists for this purpose?

UPDATE: This is programming related because blacklisting is a common programming task. And programmers are one of the few groups that care about this type of data. Who else would I ask?

Comment: and this is **programming-related** how?

Comment: I wish to block users based on IP address. Downloading my software. I need to know how to do this. i.e. where I can get the data. Who else would care?

Comment: The [major hosts of spammers/among The World's Worst Spam Support ISPs][2]. 

  [2]: https://www.spamhaus.org/statistics/networks/
are(as of Nov 2021[2]):
1. microsoft.com 
2. cloudflare.com 
3. google.com 
4. chinanet-gd  
5. uninet.net.mx 
6. chinanet-js  
7. wind.com.do  
8. chinanet-zj  
9. chinanet-hb  
10. stc.com.sa  
If it's not clear, theres plenty of info at the cited source.  It would be nice to be able to post this as an answer.

Comment: Or it could be moved to security.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

South America in General, but mostly Brazil

China and Korea

South Eastern Europe: Hungary, Czech, etc.

Comment: Sources for this information?

Comment: Mostly personal experience. I run some pretty high volume email servers and an IT company. 9 out of 10 times, I'll see some fish activity and trace it back to one of these three sets of countries.

Answer (score 2):

Primarily, the basement of their parents place.  :)